# Why does my aspdotnetstorefront instance restart when I connect to it for the first time everyday

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, restart, aspdotnetstorefront

I have a developer instance of aspdotnetstorefront that no one else is using. Everytime I get to the ecommerce front end or the admin backend for the first time in the day, it restarts with a yellow screen (in my browser).

At times it even restarts while in the middle of adding items to the cart.

I understand that the application has been taken off and it is loaded up the first time I send a request, but why bring up that yellow screen stating that the application is restarting when it is actually starting.

Is there any configuration in the storefront that controls this behaviour.

All I want is that it should just start up and show me the screen I requested without the yellow screen (I don't have a problem with the first request taking longer to serve).

[image]

Comment: You have a yellow screen? Could mean lots of things. Perhaps your monitor is going bad, or your videocard, or your cables. Oh, you mean an error screen?! Yeah, perhaps if you told us what the error is, we could assist with that rather than being forced to make wild guesses.

Comment: If you have worked with Aspdotnetstorefront you would know what yellow screen I am referring to. I will have to wait for another day till I get it again. Tomorrow I will post the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

You may have two separate issues here.

1. app startup, AspDotNetStorefront has startup routines when it is initially loaded in to memory. The process does several things but one very expensive and time consuming operation is re-encrypting all encrypted data, eg. customer passwords, and sensitive transaction data. The reason it does this is because it has no mechanism to determine if your encryption key has changed between startups to it just runs the process every initial load. On most storefronts this time is negligible. If you have a lot of customer data and or a lot of order history because you do not have an archive and purge strategy then this process can become time consuming and initially cause the timeout error. The second time you run it your sql server cache is most likely primed and runs operations within the default time out period.

   To fix this you would have to go in to db.cs and depending on the version of AspDotNetStorefront you will want to find the correct place to set the connection timeout period on your SqlCommand Object.

   Also you will get the initial load issue anytime IIS unloads the application from memory. By default IIS automatically unload the app if there has been no activity for 20 minutes.
2. Your add to cart issue could be caused for various reasons and we would need detailed error information to be able to help you troubleshoot. I can only guess that you are getting a generic message about setting custom errors to off. If that isn't clear enough there are good instructions found here: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/programming/custom-errors/

Comment: I just got the yellow screen that I was referring to in the question and have added the screen shot. If seeing the screen shot changes your answer in anyway, please update your answer for everyone to benefit. Thanks in advance.